# How to allow middle-clicks to close last tab on Firefox 3.5?

Tags: firefox

A middle-click on a tab will close a tab on Firefox except for the last tab. I know that there is some setting somewhere that allows this because I have one PC set up long ago which does this, and one PC which I set up recently which doesn't.

Closing the last tab causes it to turn into a blank page.

Does anyone know how to switch this setting on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this article : ["Closing the last tab in Firefox 3.5"](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/closing-the-last-tab-in-firefox-35/) for how to manually do this.
The article also recommends this add-on : [Last Tab Close Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12991/), which quote "shows Close button on the last tab in Firefox 3.5*, which closes the last tab but not the browser".

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware of that `about:config` thing. Is there any explanation of all the settings found there?

Comment: See [About:config - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config).

Answer (score 3):

Try using [TabMixPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122). Among other things, it can set this behavior to what you want. It also has a lot o other nice features that you might like.

Answer (score 0):

try setting in about:config

- [MiddleMouse key](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Middlemouse.)
- [MouseWheel key](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Mousewheel.)