# Close Firefox window with middle click on last tab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

This is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/37020/how-to-allow-middle-clicks-to-close-last-tab-on-firefox-3-5), but unfortunately the accepted answer is a link to a website that my work proxy is failing to resolve. As such, I thought I would ask again in the hope that someone can answer in-line.

1. Firefox 4 with 1 tab open
2. I middle click on the last tab.
3. Nothing happens.

I instead expect Firefox to close (i.e. Chrome's behaviour). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That answer linked to an article describing how to close the last tab. It suggests you type `about:config` in the address bar, search for `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab` and set it to `false`. Firefox doesn't seem to close though, according to that post. Open it in Google's cache if you want to read the whole article.

Comment: I second Daniel. Just tested it. With the above steps, Firefox 4.0.1 does not close. It only removes the site in the last tab.

Comment: Thanks for checking out the link for me, and the advice for using Google's cache. The main annoyance for me is the inconsistency - if I can still press Ctrl+W and close the window, why is middle click disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension "Tab Mix Plus" might do what you want as it has options about what to do when you close the last tab. (Just checked and it worked as you want on my PC.)

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! This plugin has a lot of options tangential to the feature I'm looking for. Assuming it doesn't modify any of my other settings then it will be perfect!